# Does Azure DevOps provide persistent storage for its builds?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to develop an Azure DevOps build that needs to read some data and after the build update that data. My options currently are:

1. **Associate the data with the build as an artifact. The next build will know to look at the previous build for that artifact and thus will get the required data.** Relies on the presence of the previous build, i.e. if anyone accidentally deletes it - poof. Also, if anyone screws the retention policy - poof.
2. **Store the data as file in the Git repo, either the one containing the build or a dedicated one.** - the build will have to push the changes to the repo. In case of a dedicated repo, one will have to fetch the data manually also.
3. A dedicated storage somewhere.

I am not particularly keen on hacking my way through with the items (1) and (2). Item (3) seems the most straightforward way, but then I have to maintain this separate storage. Even if it is the simplest blob storage in Azure.

Is there a better way?

**EDIT 1**

By scanning the Azure DevOps REST API documentation I came across this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/properties?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Never used it before, but it does seem to match my needs. I do not need to store a lot of data. Wonder if anyone has any experience with the build properties and if there are any gotchas there.

**EDIT 2**

I need to store less than 1K of textual information. I could store it in a file on a shared drive, but then there is too much maintenance headache - one need to make sure the permissions are right and that nobody deletes this file.

At the end I decided to store the information in the definition of the build I develop using the following powershell code:

```
$DefaultStateKey = "3edac6eed15745eb960e20b53e2bba68"

function ExtractValue($res, $StateKey)
{
    $res = $res.value.$StateKey.'$value'
    if ($res)
    {
        $res = $res | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
    $res
}

function Get-State(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TfsProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$BuildDefId,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$StateKey = $DefaultStateKey)
{
    $url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/$TfsProject/_apis/build/definitions/$BuildDefId/properties?$TfsApiVersion-preview.1"
    ExtractValue $(Invoke-RestMethod $url -UseDefaultCredentials) $StateKey
}

function Set-State(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$TfsProject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]$BuildDefId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][AllowNull()]$value,
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]$StateKey = $DefaultStateKey)
{
    $url = "$TfsInstanceUrl/$TfsProject/_apis/build/definitions/$BuildDefId/properties?$TfsApiVersion-preview.1"
    $Body = @{
        path = "/$StateKey"
    }
    if ($null -eq $value)
    {
        $Body.op = 'Remove'
    }
    else
    {
        $Body.op = 'Add'
        $Body.value = $value | ConvertTo-Json    
    }
    $Body = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
    ExtractValue $(Invoke-RestMethod $url `
        -UseDefaultCredentials `
        -Method Patch `
        -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" `
        -Body "[$Body]") $StateKey
}
```

Comment: Which kind of data is this?

Comment: It can be arranged in one or more json files. Could be one, because I do not expect it to be large.

Comment: why would you think you need to manually fetch data in the second case?

Comment: Because Azure DevOps build can only fetch data from one source. If my data is in a dedicated git repo, then the build is already bound to the Git repo containing the build source code. Hence, I will have to fetch manually from the other Git repo.

Comment: Do you want to store the properties obtained with the rest api? Where do you want to store the properties, stored in a file or somewhere else?